# Why Pandavas did not kill Shakuni in the first day

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas, kauravas, shakuni

Why did the Pandavas delay killing of Shakuni?

Specifically, I think if Shakuni was killed in the first day itself ( which I think was easy), the Mahabharata war would have greatly reduced in intensity and I think would have finished earlier. This is because, he was the main antagonist who ignited Duryodhana more and more. If we remove the fuel for Duryodhana, then chances are that he would have surrendered to Pandavas seeing the immense stalemate like situation between Bhishma and Arjuna.

Any light on these facts based on scriptural anecdotes? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: There is a chance that your question may be closed as opinion based. You should change the title of the question.

Comment: @hanugm thanks! edited.

Comment: By the time they reached the point of war, Shakuni had done his worst already. His presence in the war was very minor. He was not a specially significant warrior like Drona or Bhishma who could alter the outcome of the war.